# How to short a string array, but keep the format of the entire line in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, quicksort

I want to short a array with Strings but i cant keep the entire format of the string as it is...

For example i have this array:

```
        String A={ 0.01%%name1 , 0.5%%name2, 1.0%%name3  0.6%%name4,  1.2%%name5}
```

i want sort a String array ( **x[ ]** ) it like this:

```
                                     1.2  name5
                                     1.0  name3
                                     0.6  name4
                                     0.5  name2
                                     0.01 name1
```

So far this code make the sort but the names dont appear to been sorted. Any idea?

```
  String[] top5Matches = new String[10];
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
  String[] parts = x[i].split("%%"); 
  top5Matches[i]=parts[0];   
   }
  Arrays.sort(top5Matches);
 for(int i=0;i<Database_len;i++)
   {
      System.out.println(top5Matches[i]);   
   }
```

results so far....

```
     0.01
     0.05
     0.05
     1.0
     1.2
```

Comment: So, you want to sort by the numeric part, descending?

Comment: Do you only need to sort the array or also convert the values as per your expected result?

Comment: when you show code to others.. please format it..

Comment: Actually ascending order but i can handle it and with both ways

Comment: ok @Tim Castelijns, because its my first post when u say format it? (what i have to change?)

Comment: that's not relevant. You have to format it, like, in your IDE

Comment: @Mena i whant to sort the array but keep the names of the line... for example if i have string A {  2%%name1, 0%%name2 , 3%%name3}  i want as result :: 3 name 3 , 2 name1 ,0 name2

Comment: You should create a class for the objects represented by those strings, convert the strings to those objects, sort them using a Comparator, then print them in a loop, using a stern for a 1-line solution.

Comment: first sort the array then use a two dimensional array and place parts[1] into the second dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Write some model class like **(or use Map)**:

```
class Element {
    String name;
    float value;
}
```

Create elements and add to array:

```
Element el1 = new Element();
Element el2 = new Element();
```

Sort the array by value (or other way you want) and print results.

```
For(Element el: elements){
    System.out.pritnln(el.value + "\t" + el.name)
}
```